# When is the matrix $\mathbf{Y}=\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^{T}\mathbf{A}^{T}$ a symmetric matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

let $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$.

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{Y}=\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^{T}\mathbf{A}^{T}
\end{equation}

Can we say that $\mathbf{Y}$ is always a symmetric matrix when $\mathbf{A}$ is not necessarily symmetric.

Comment: Yes. Just compute $\mathbf Y^T$.

Comment: Oops….how could I miss that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $ (AB)^T=B^TA^T$ and $(A^T)^T=A$, for all matrices $A,B$ we have:

$$
Y^T=\left(Axx^TA^T\right)^T=\left(x^TA^T\right)^T\left(Ax\right)^T=Axx^TA^T=Y
$$